# How can i call inherited overloaded operator << and add more text in output in derived class?

Tags: c++, class, object, inheritance, operator-overloading

i have base class Karta, and derived class Borac. In class Karta i overloaded operator <<, but in derived class(Borac) i want to call function operator<<() for base class and then add more text to the final output.
How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call a specific overload, you can cast the respective parameter to the type expected by that specific overload:

```
struct Base {
};

struct Derived : public Base {
};

std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream & o, const struct Base &b) {
    o << "Base;";
    return o;
}


std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream & o, const struct Derived &d) {
    o << dynamic_cast<const Base&>(d);
    o << "Derived;";
    return o;
}

int main() {
    Derived d;
    std::cout << d << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Base;Derived;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you meant `operator<<` for `std::ostream`, you can cast `Borac` to `Karta` to use base class operator (and then append anything specific for `Borac`). Otherwise, if your operator is class member, you can use [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61727313/7976805).

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Borac& b) {
    os << dynamic_cast<const Karta&>(b);
    os << "Additional part for Borac";
    return os;
}
```

[See it online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mKDZ7sRZEOhGm6iD)

Answer (score 0):

In order to call a base class function, specify the base class name prepended to the function similar to namespace syntax:

```
Type Borac::operator<<() {
    Karta::operator<<(); // calls operator<<() of the Karta class on this
    // Here goes any additional code
}
```